# How to check if a user uploaded a file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, file-upload

I made a PHP page and I want to check if a user selected a file and CSV file checkbox is checked no error occurs. I used the following code:

```
 $file = $fu['filepath'].$fu['filename'];
        $handle=fopen($file,"r");
        while($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024)){
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='receptionts[]' checked='checked' value='".$row[1] ."' /> ".$row[0]." <br />";
        }
```

When user does not select a file for upload it gives errors, see below:

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty
Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Comment: give validation & check user uploads file or not??

Comment: but how i validate user uploads file or not in the above code

Comment: try like this <?php if($_FILES['your_field_name']['name'] != '') { *** your above code *** } else { *** error to show *** } ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = $fu['filepath'].$fu['filename'];
$handle=@fopen($file,"r");
if($handle) {
  while($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='receptionts[]' checked='checked' value='".$row[1] ."' /> ".$row[0]." <br />";
  }
} else {
  // File doesn't exist. do something.
}
```